# Unable to create new Microsoft user Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Google Auth correctly in my web app, but I'm having issues with Microsoft Auth.
When implemented following the instructions from [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#web-v8_3), I can see the redirect correctly, but when it redirects back to the app, I get the following error:

```
auth.esm.js:221 POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=AIzaSyBam7rlhnpdofW0BkLXBIgZLBPfzL7akqA 400
```

In Firebase Console, Microsoft Auth is enabled and configured

Comment: You have shared the request URL and not the error returned.

Comment: It can't post after the login, that's the error. I can't figure out what is causing it to fail, because the login via Google can register new users in firebase auth

Comment: If you open the network tab in dev tools, click on the request which returned error and open response tab, it should contain some error.

Comment: Thank you, the message contains the following error: "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Error getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://[app].firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler . Im doing more research, the uri is setted in the uri redirect at Azure. localhost is setted as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone has this error in the future:
The full error message was

```
    "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Error getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://[app].firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client&error_description=AADSTS7000215:%20Invalid%20client%20secret%20is%20provided.%0D%0ATrace%20ID:%20eeb1ec6a-d835-4338-bd71-51f414ed8d00%0D%0ACorrelation%20ID:%20050706e3-97aa-4f13-b0a9-a55bb3a9aae8%0D%0ATimestamp:%202021-08-25%2018:47:47Z&timestamp=2021-08-25%2018:47:47Z&trace_id=[id]&correlation_id=[id]8&error_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code%3D7000215, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=401, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null, crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null, crossOriginResourcePolicy=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n, contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], varyHeaderNames=[], cookieList=[]}}",
```

The key is 'ADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.'
It turns out I was setting the Id Secret instead of the value of the secret.
[image]
It works completely fine after I changed it.